# How to expand Windows Explorer folder to show only the immediate child folders?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Is there a command to tell Windows Explorer to display for a folder only the immediate child subfolders, rather than the fully or partially expanded tree beneath this folder?  This was easy to do in File Manager and quite useful.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Windows? Using what method to do the expansion? As far as I know, opening one level at a time is the default behavior.

Comment: If you press the cross icon to the left of the folder in the folder tree, by default it will only display 1 level of child folders, as Dennis points out.  Any other behaviour is the result of a modification, and could probably be rolled back.

Comment: If you haven't already you could take a look at [xplorer2](http://zabkat.com), a Windows Explorer alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows 7, Windows Explorer does show only the immediate child subfolders in the default behavior.

I think more information would be needed to understand the problem that led to the original question.

In order to move this question toward close (since it doesn't seem clear from the original description what the issue is), I am summarizing the info given by Dennis and Steve in the comments.